# Using 100% of CPU in MATLAB 2013a (matlabpool)

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I just switched to MATLAB 2013a and the command `matlabpool` is only opening 4 workers and not 8 like in 2012a. So it is running only 50% of the CPU. Is there a way to go up to 100% with 2013a? Is somebody experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
matlabpool open 8
```

This allows you to specify how many workers you want. For more details refer to the [`matlabpool` documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/matlabpool.html).

Comment: Thank you it leads me to the right way. It was also necessary to increase the NumWorkers before you can use a higher amount of clusters.

Answer (score 1):

To explain your observed behaviour: MATLAB and Parallel Computing Toolbox both use the number of "real" cores on your system, not counting hyperthreading. This gives better performance under many conditions.

Comment: Thank you, that explains all my observations!